# How to access <a> tag which is present inside <th> in VBA that doesn't have id or classname?

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to automate the web form where I have `<a>` tag which is inside `<th>` tag. When I tried `getElementByTagName("a").innerText` I'm not getting the desired element/text. But when I wrote `getElementByTagName("th").innerText` it is showing me the exact text that I'm pointing at. But the issue is I wanted to click on the link which this text i.e `<a>` tag has. `getElementByTagName("th").Click` is not working. Can someone please help?

Comment: Instead of returning innerText, do a subsequent search within the node. In this case, if <a> is right beneath <th> it would be the first child node that you want. In more complex cases, you can still use getElementByTagName of children too.

Comment: Please provide the relevant html and website link if public.

Comment: Try innerHTML instead of innerText

Comment: FYI: There is no `getElementByTagName` method. It is `Elements`

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method as `getElementByTagName()`.

There are: `document.getElementsByTagName()` and `Element.getElementsByTagName()`. Both return a live `HTMLCollection`.

In the latter `Element` refers to a DOM element. It allows you to search for specific tags in children of that element.

Plese refer to the following MDN documents:

- [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)
- [Document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Also, it's worth mentioning that, without `document.*` or anything else, the browser would assume you're trying to call `window.getElementByTagName()`.

***NOTE:** I'm aware the question is tagged `vba` instead of `javascript`, but in this case it doesn't seem to matter.*